# Build an array from 3 arrays with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, each

I've some problem to construct an array.

Array A:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-13
    [1] => 2015-09-14
    [2] => 2015-09-15
    [3] => 2015-09-16
    [4] => 2015-09-17
    [5] => 2015-09-18
    [6] => 2015-09-19
)
```

Array B:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
)
```

Array C:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Leaves-19
    [1] => Shifts-18
    [2] => Shifts-18
    [3] => Shifts-18
    [4] => Shifts-18
    [5] => Shifts-18
    [6] => Leaves-19
    [7] => Leaves-19
    [8] => Shifts-12
    [9] => Shifts-12
    [10] => Shifts-12
    [11] => Shifts-12
    [12] => Shifts-12
    [13] => Leaves-19
)
```

Desired final output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-13|1|Leaves-19
    [1] => 2015-09-14|1|Shifts-18
    [2] => 2015-09-15|1|Shifts-18
    [3] => 2015-09-16|1|Shifts-18
    [4] => 2015-09-17|1|Shifts-18
    [5] => 2015-09-18|1|Shifts-18
    [6] => 2015-09-19|1|Leaves-19
    [7] => 2015-09-13|8|Leaves-19
    [8] => 2015-09-14|8|Shifts-12
    [9] => 2015-09-15|8|Shifts-12
    [10] => 2015-09-16|8|Shifts-12
    [11] => 2015-09-17|8|Shifts-12
    [12] => 2015-09-18|8|Shifts-12
    [13] => 2015-09-19|8|Leaves-19
)
```

I'm lost in `for` and `foreach`.

**Here's the logic:**

- `1st parameter` is a date and it come's form `array B`. It is repeat
  after 6 entries.
- `2nd parameter` is the user id. It changes after 6 entries and pass to the next id.
- `3rd parameter` is an entry of `array B`.

**Oter informations:**

- The arrays don't have the same length.
- `Array A`, counts 6 entries.
- `Array B`, counts a random entries.
- `Array C`, is `Array A` x 2.

I already tried to make a `for` for my `array B` and after a foreach in `array A`, but it wasn't functional.

I do not know where I need to start.

Hope I will have any help or cue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to explain the logic of how the arrays are related, and what you've actually tried so far. "I do not know where I need to start" is not really much of a research effort.

Comment: Is array C always the same length of the final array? And is the final array always `count(A) * count(B)` in length?

Comment: @rjdown: Question edited. Hope it will help.

Comment: Do the array size will remain same??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [modulus operator](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)

```
$OutputArray = Array();

for($i=0; $i < max(count($a1),count($a2),count($a3)); $i++){
  array_push($OutputArray, $a1[ $i % count($a1) ] . "|" . 
             $a2[ $i % count($a2) ] . "|" . $a3[ $i % count($a3) ]);
}

print_r($OutputArray);
```

you get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-13|1|Leaves-19
    [1] => 2015-09-14|8|Shifts-18
    [2] => 2015-09-15|1|Shifts-18
    [3] => 2015-09-16|8|Shifts-18
    [4] => 2015-09-17|1|Shifts-18
    [5] => 2015-09-18|8|Shifts-18
    [6] => 2015-09-19|1|Leaves-19
    [7] => 2015-09-13|8|Leaves-19
    [8] => 2015-09-14|1|Shifts-12
    [9] => 2015-09-15|8|Shifts-12
    [10] => 2015-09-16|1|Shifts-12
    [11] => 2015-09-17|8|Shifts-12
    [12] => 2015-09-18|1|Shifts-12
    [13] => 2015-09-19|8|Leaves-19
)
```

if you want in order (expected):

```
$OutputArray = Array();

$max = max(count($a1),count($a2),count($a3));
for($i=0; $i < $max; $i++){
  array_push($OutputArray, $a1[$i%count($a1)] . "|" . 
             $a2[ $i*count($a2) / $max ] . "|" . $a3[$i%count($a3)]);
}

print_r($OutputArray);
```

you get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-13|1|Leaves-19
    [1] => 2015-09-14|1|Shifts-18
    [2] => 2015-09-15|1|Shifts-18
    [3] => 2015-09-16|1|Shifts-18
    [4] => 2015-09-17|1|Shifts-18
    [5] => 2015-09-18|1|Shifts-18
    [6] => 2015-09-19|1|Leaves-19
    [7] => 2015-09-13|8|Leaves-19
    [8] => 2015-09-14|8|Shifts-12
    [9] => 2015-09-15|8|Shifts-12
    [10] => 2015-09-16|8|Shifts-12
    [11] => 2015-09-17|8|Shifts-12
    [12] => 2015-09-18|8|Shifts-12
    [13] => 2015-09-19|8|Leaves-19
)
```

Comment: It didn't seem to do what the OP needed at the Array B part.

Comment: @AlanMachado actually it does, you get the same values just in a different sort order.

Comment: Look like it works. Only one thing: I normally must have 13 entries. With your code I code 14. So I just remove the equal sign.

Comment: That was a fine algorithm, sir!  I was working toward a similar end, but you can type faster!  lol.

Comment: @ABC The desired output in your question SHOWS 14 elements!  I would upvote this answer again, if I could!

Comment: @Jose Ricardo Bustos M. : Pride to get this marvellous code in my projet. I add a comment in it. :)

Comment: @stubsthewizard: Mine was from `0 to 13`. His answer with the equal sign goes from `0 to 14`. That's not a real problem. :)

Comment: @Abc.  I guess I am not seeing something you see.  No worries, though. We can agree it is a stellar algorithm.  Be sure to accept it as the correct answer, if it pleases you.

Comment: @Abc I fixed problem 14 elemens

Comment: @AlanMachado I add solution with expected order

Comment: @stubsthewizard I fixed problem 14 elemens

Comment: @Abc The only thing I would do differently, is that rather than using a pipe as a delimiter, I would make it an array of arrays.  Personal preference, but I think it ends up cleaner that way.  Great Question and great answer!

Comment: Hey @JoseRicardoBustosM.: if I add a new param in `array b`, it do not work... I do not why.

Comment: http://codepad.org/PnAFG8cx It should show 66 elements in the final array (22 x 3) where 22 is the count of dates and 3 the count of users.

Comment: @Abc `count($a1) * count($a2)` instead of `max(count($a1),count($a2),count($a3))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it iterates over the biggest array and condition the counting of the minor ones to its desired listing behavior.

```
<?php

$arrA = ['2015-09-13','2015-09-14','2015-09-15','2015-09-16',
        '2015-09-17','2015-09-18','2015-09-19'];
$arrB = [1,8];
$arrC = ['Leaves-19','Shifts-18','Shifts-18','Shifts-18','Shifts-18','Shifts-18',
'Leaves-19','Leaves-19','Shifts-12','Shifts-12','Shifts-12','Shifts-12','Shifts-12',
'Leaves-19'];
$a = $b = 0;

for ($c = 0; $c < count($arrC); $c++) {
    $arrC[$c] = $arrA[$a].'|'.$arrB[$b].'|'.$arrC[$c];
    $a++;
    if ($a == count($arrA)) {
        $a = 0;
        $b++;
    }
};

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrC);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-13|1|Leaves-19
    [1] => 2015-09-14|1|Shifts-18
    [2] => 2015-09-15|1|Shifts-18
    [3] => 2015-09-16|1|Shifts-18
    [4] => 2015-09-17|1|Shifts-18
    [5] => 2015-09-18|1|Shifts-18
    [6] => 2015-09-19|1|Leaves-19
    [7] => 2015-09-13|8|Leaves-19
    [8] => 2015-09-14|8|Shifts-12
    [9] => 2015-09-15|8|Shifts-12
    [10] => 2015-09-16|8|Shifts-12
    [11] => 2015-09-17|8|Shifts-12
    [12] => 2015-09-18|8|Shifts-12
    [13] => 2015-09-19|8|Leaves-19
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, I have named your 3 arrays as `$arrA`, `$arrB` and `$arrC`

```
$arrA = Array(
  '2015-09-13',
  '2015-09-14',
  '2015-09-15',
  '2015-09-16',
  '2015-09-17',
  '2015-09-18',
  '2015-09-19'
);
$arrB = array(1,8);
$arrC  = array(
  'Leaves-19',
  'Shifts-18',
  'Shifts-18',
  'Shifts-18',
  'Shifts-18',
  'Shifts-18',
  'Leaves-19',
  'Leaves-19',
  'Shifts-12',
  'Shifts-12',
  'Shifts-12',
  'Shifts-12',
  'Shifts-12',
  'Leaves-19'
);

$output = array();
$indx = 0;
foreach($arrB as $b){
    foreach($arrA as $a){
        $output[] = $a.'|'.$b.'|'.$arrC[$indx];
        $indx++;/*new line addded*/
    }
    //$indx++;/*remove this line from here*/
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Do you think Array C gets incremented every step?

Comment: Not really what it was excepted about the 3rd parameter.

Comment: And where is the 3rd parameter `Shifts-12`. :(

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
$arrayA = array('2015-09-13','2015-09-14','2015-09-15','2015-09-16','2015-09-17','2015-09-18','2015-09-19');
$arrayB = array(1,8);
$arrayC = array('Leaves-19','Leaves-18','Leaves-17','Leaves-16','Leaves-15','Leaves-14','Leaves-13','Leaves-12','Leaves-11','Leaves-10','Leaves-9','Leaves-8','Leaves-7','leaves-6');
$output = array();
$count = 0;

foreach($arrayB as $arrayBElement){
    foreach($arrayA as $arrayAElement){
        $output[] = $arrayC[$count] . '|' . $arrayAElement . '|' . $arrayBElement;
        $count++;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

E: removed erroneous count

Comment: Edit and keep array C at the end, B in middle and A at starting

Answer (score 0):

This stinks of a [homework problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) so I'm going to answer in pseudocode so hopefully you can apply some hints and come to the solution yourself.

It appears that maybe Array B (`[1,8]`) is a list of indexes at which to start printing out the next index. Your own statement (`2nd parameter is the user id. It changes after 6 entries and pass to the next id.`) is not accurate based on your desired final output:

```
[6] => 2015-09-19|1|Leaves-19
[7] => 2015-09-13|8|Leaves-19
```

This moves to the next `id` at index 7 (count 8) not index 6 (count 7, or one after 6 entries).

So My pseudo solution would be this:

- Create a new array by repeating Array A until it matches the length of Array C
- Append Array B to Array A by finding the element of Array B that is equal to or less than `(1+index)`:

  `0 => '1', 1 => '1' ... 7 => '8'`
- Concatenate Array C to every array with index parity (eg. `newArray[ 0 ] . ArrayC[ 0 ]`)

This gives you the final output you desire.

Answer (score -1):

With different sizes try guess maxlength

```
//Create arrays
var Adates= ["2015-09-13", "2015-09-14", "2015-09-15"];
var Bnums= ["1", "2", "3"];
var Cnums= ["Leaves-19", "Shifts-18", "Shifts-18"];

//get size
var maxLenght=0;
if(Adates.length>maxLenght) maxLenght=Adates.length;
if(Bnums.length>maxLenght) maxLenght=Bnums.length;
if(Cnums.length>maxLenght) maxLenght=Cnums.length;

//merge and populate
var OutputArray;
for (i = 0; i < maxLenght; i++) {
      OutputArray[i]=Adates[i]+"|"+Bnums[i]+"|"+Cnums[i];
}
```

Comment: is this javascript? I believe OP is targeting PHP.